# Resizing individual Text Objects

Tags: java, javafx-8

Over the last week or 2, I've been experimenting with different ways to manipulate shape and text objects in a scene using JavaFX.

Currently, I'm looking at creating new text objects and being able to manipulate their size.

So I have a scene, with a button that simply says "Text", that once pressed
creates a TextField whereby upon entering text into this field creates a new text object. There is also a slider which you're able to use to change the size of the text object. and you're able to drag the various Text objects about

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class CreatingNewText extends Application
{
    private int size;
    private TextField enterText;
    private Slider sizeSlider;
    private Button button;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        // Button for creating new text Object
        button = new Button("text");
        button.setLayoutX(200);

        // Slider for Size
        sizeSlider = new Slider(0,255,0);
        sizeSlider.setLayoutX(250);
        sizeSlider.setLayoutY(0);

        // Button functionality
        button.setOnAction(e ->{
            Text text = new Text(150,300,"Text");
            // Moving created text
            text.setOnMouseDragged(f ->{
            text.setX(f.getX());
            text.setY(f.getY());
            });
            text.setLayoutX(300);
            text.setLayoutY(300);
            text.setFont(Font.font("Phosphate"));
            // Text entry field
            enterText = new TextField();
            text.textProperty().bind(enterText.textProperty());
            // Slider functionality
            text.setOnMouseEntered(g ->{    
            });
            sizeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue
                <? extends Number> ov, Number curVal, Number newVal) ->     {
                    size = (int) sizeSlider.getValue();
                    Font fontSize = Font.font(size);
                    text.setFont(fontSize);
                });
            root.getChildren().addAll(enterText,text);
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(button,sizeSlider);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The issues -

1. I cannot change the size of a specific text object - I understand that every time I create a new text object it assigns it to the "text" variable, and so upon altering the size with the slider all Text shapes associated with "text" will change also, how can this be corrected?
2. I am also sure the same thing is happening for the text field - every time the text button is pushed it just creates a new textfield which just sits on top of the old one. I have tried creating my textfield outside of the action event - similar to the slider, but cannot because the text object is local to the action event. Making "text" an instance variable just complicates things and I receive an "exception in application start method" error - So basically it doesn't work. Really what I want is just the one text field that can create multiple text objects

Apologies about the code. I am very inexperienced and it even looks a mess to me. Hope the question makes sense too

Comment: For issue 2 : Why are you creating an other textfield. What is it's purpose ??

Comment: Its not an intentional thing I only want the one textfield, but If i follow the same approach as I did for creating my slider, it doesn't work because text is local to the action event.

Comment: There is no probleme putting textfield like the slider and the button just move the line `enterText = new TextField();` below `sizeSlider.setLayoutY(0);` and check your addAll `root.getChildren().addAll(text);`  `root.getChildren().addAll(button,sizeSlider, entertext);`

Comment: For issue 1 : If you want to select text for individuel resize just add an mouseclick Handler and resize only this one

Comment: @user43968, for issue 2, thats great, haha I thought i tried that, obviously not, thanks, its introduced some odd behaviour but its a step in the right direction i feel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this sample app made from your code. I think it demonstrates what you are trying to achieve :

Click on a text it become Red and you can adjust it's size with your slider

```
public class CreatingNewText extends Application {
private int size;
private TextField enterText;
private Slider sizeSlider;
private Button button;

private Text selected;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    // Button for creating new text Object
    button = new Button("text");
    button.setLayoutX(200);

    // Slider for Size
    sizeSlider = new Slider(0, 255, 0);
    sizeSlider.setLayoutX(250);
    sizeSlider.setLayoutY(0);

    // TextField
    enterText = new TextField();

    // Button functionality
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        Text text = new Text(150, 300, "Text");
        // Moving created text
        text.setOnMouseDragged(f -> {
            text.setX(f.getX());
            text.setY(f.getY());
        });
        text.setLayoutX(300);
        text.setLayoutY(300);
        text.setFont(Font.font("Phosphate"));

        text.textProperty().bind(enterText.textProperty());

        text.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, mouseEvent -> {

            if (selected != null) {
                selected.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            }

            selected = (Text) mouseEvent.getTarget();
            selected.setFill(Color.RED);

        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(text);
    });

    sizeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number curVal, Number newVal) -> {

            if (selected != null) {
            size = (int) sizeSlider.getValue();
            Font fontSize = Font.font(size);
            selected.setFont(fontSize);
        }
    });

    root.getChildren().addAll(button, sizeSlider, enterText);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Comment: thats great, exactly what i wanted + an additional red highlight mechanism! Thanks, its appreciated